# Why don't you delete older questions for Android?

Tags: discussion, questions

When I have some problem about Android programming (be it for Eclipse or Android studio) there are always many questions from 2+ years ago, and most of the time, those questions and answers are not helpful, because of the now old and irrelevant info provided.

Don't you think such questions should be deleted? I can personally Flag any questions I stumble upon, which I see are not helpful anymore.

Comment: *Not helpful* to whom? *Most of the time* does not mean *all the time*.

Comment: I highly doubt that someone is interested in the Gradle Plugin version from 2 years ago, for example...

Comment: Well, you never know. Someone could be stuck on a platform from two years ago and depend on that plugin. I would leave the questions around, it's not like they're taking up too much space or something.

Comment: its not about the space, how many people are searching for old and deprecated information, and how many are searching for actual, up-to-date information, and they get confused from the old answers and questions?

Comment: I don't think anyone is getting confused. I'll try to find a duplicate with our rationale, I think there is one somewhere.

Comment: not everyone is experienced like you, you know

Comment: Thank you, but there are hordes of people with more experience than me on Meta :)

Comment: I was talking about programming

Comment: Hrm, I can't seem to find an appropriate duplicate. I found [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11705/how-to-deal-with-obsolete-answers) on the Overmeta but it's about answers, not questions.

Comment: [New android questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+created%3A1y..)

Answer (score 12):

SO shouldn't delete posts based on their age. Just because a question or answer is old, doesn't make it obsolete.

People could be using older versions of libraries, or a question could simply still be relevant / correct, to date.

Even if deletion of old posts were an option, there is no way to properly filter what can, and what can't be deleted. You can't place a blanket ban on questions tagged [x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x) of a certain age, because then you'll always get too many good posts that are going to get deleted. Even posts that have no votes can still be relevant today.

Comment: "Just because a question or answer is old, doesn't make it obsolete." - sometime it does

Comment: @Borislav No. Just in that context means "solely". You can't have "sometimes". It is not just a semantic point. One person's "old" is another person's "this is what I'm working with and upgrading is not an option". As an example, there are still important systems compiled with programs written to the 1974 COBOL Standard. Even though there was a new Standard last year, and a couple in between. Any question related to COBOL to the 1974 Standard is certainly not obsolete. On a smaller scale, your Android will be similar.

Comment: @Borislav While I agree that in the world of Android and iOS obsolete generally means not in use (especially for iOS, which forces app developers to use their new standards), there is an argument for keeping old answers right here: [link](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html).  According to Google there are still active devices with Froyo, which was released back in 2010. Their disclaimer also says that they don't track older versions of Android so it's likely that even those are still in use.

Answer (score 8):

SO aims to be a reference for Q&A. As such, you can find recent or older information. But I do not agree with you when you say that outdated information should be deleted. I recently answered a question about Struts 1.2, with references to Apache Cactus that is *in the attic* (explicitly retired) since 2011. Because OP had to used those damned outdated tools.

I'm not an expert on Android development, but can you be sure that some corporate tools are not still based on what you consider as outdated?

Anyway, SO's search engine is smart enough to allow you to filter posts older than a certain date. Extract from [How do I search? - Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) (just a **short** extract - you should read the whole page):

> You can use specific dates or date ranges to narrow results down to posts created or active within a certain time period, using the following operators:
>
> - created: to specify when the posts were created
> - lastactive: for posts active in a specified time period
>
> ... if you want to see all the posts active in the last 5 months, use `lastactive:6m..` On June 15, that will show posts from January 15 up to the most recently active. You can close the range as well: lastactive:3m..1m

That means that if you only want to search recent posts, you can. And people needing references on old systems still can find them. No need to remove anything.

Comment: Here's what I'd like, a smarter search that lets me do something like "-androidVersion:<2.2"